# Execute HQL file with beeline command

Tags: sql, hive, beeline

i'm trying to execute a query in a test.hql with beeline and i'm not getting results

here the command :

```
beeline -u "jdbc:hive2://master01:2181,master02:2181,master03:2181/;serviceDiscoveryMode=zooKeeper;zooKeeperNamespace=hiveserver2" -f test.hql
```

in test.hql file :

```
select * from db1.tab1 limit 20;
```

But if i execute the command with the parameter -e which execute directly the query,it gives me the results

```
beeline -u "jdbc:hive2://master01:2181,master02:2181,master03:2181/;serviceDiscoveryMode=zooKeeper;zooKeeperNamespace=hiveserver2" -e "select * from db1.tab1 limit 20;"
```

Am i missing something ?

Comment: Did you save the file with the query?

Answer (score 0):

You're right. `-e` is used to execute one or multiple queries and see the result.

`-f` is mostly used to run scripts like `insert into mytab select * from ourtab;` where you dont need to see all the rows.

For more options you can check-
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/hive/hiveserver2+clients#HiveServer2Clients-BeelineHiveCommands

Comment: This doesn't really answer why using a file gives no results